# Synaptics touchpad keeps disabling itself

Tags: xorg, gentoo, touchpad

I don't have any comprehensive logs right now because I bypassed the issue with `psmouse.proto=bare` but I'd really like it back.

When I use `xinput`, it simply shows up as an Elantech Touchpad, furthermore, xorg.log shows:

```
[   506.593] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event6)
[   506.593] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[   506.593] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[   506.593] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[   506.593] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad"
[   506.593] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[   506.593] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[   506.594] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   506.594]    compiled for 1.21.1.8, module version = 1.9.2
[   506.594]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   506.594]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.4
[   506.594] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[   506.594] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[   506.594] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[   506.728] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 3316 (res 31)
[   506.728] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 1837 (res 31)
[   506.728] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255
[   506.728] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 0 - 15
[   506.728] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left right double triple
[   506.728] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
[   506.728] (**) Option "FingerLow" "30"
[   506.728] (**) Option "FingerHigh" "50"
[   506.728] (**) Option "MaxTapTime" "125"
[   506.728] (**) Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
[   506.728] (**) Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
[   506.728] (**) Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
[   506.728] (**) Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
[   506.728] (**) Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
[   506.728] (**) Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
[   506.728] (**) Option "TapButton1" "1"
[   506.728] (**) Option "TapButton2" "3"
[   506.728] (**) Option "TapButton3" "2"
[   506.728] (**) Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
[   506.728] (**) Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
[   506.728] (**) Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
[   506.728] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[   506.728] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[   506.878] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event6"
[   506.878] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
[   506.878] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[   506.878] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[   506.878] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.053
[   506.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   506.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[   506.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   506.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   506.878] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[   506.878] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   506.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
```

But `synclient -l` shows `TouchpadOff=1`, passing it `TouchpadOff=0` on first glance does nothing, but `synclient TouchpadOff\=0 && synclient -l |grep TouchpadOff` does reveal that it was =0 for a short instant, but then goes back to =1 seemingly. Something seems to be constantly putting it off or there is some error why it does so itself. Is there any way to figure out what is putting it off all the time, or which of both it is?